# How can I resize an image automatically in different pages in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is a way to make a image appears with different dimensions in different pages?

I am building an e-commerce with CSS, HTML and Javascript. This website will have some catalogs with many images of the products that are for sale. In each of these images I put a heart so the custom can click on it and save the respective product in a list of favorite products, this list will be in another page.

As well as in the catalog, the products in the list will have every information about each item, including the images, but smaller.

Is it possible for me to use the same images throughout the website so that when they are shown on the list page they automatically appear smaller than the original size?

Or is the only way to do this is to resize every image for each situation?

Comment: Yes it's possible

Comment: Yep. CSS classes, and possibly CSS media queries, will do what you want.

Comment: hint: media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: You can e.g. `height: auto` to ensure the aspect ratio is maintained.

Comment: Can also generate different size files every time you upload an image, then use the size naming convention for displaying size you want in different locations. Question really lacks research effort

Comment: Thank you very much all of you. It is easier then I thought.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS `background-size` property setting it to `contain` or `cover` depending on which works best for each container.  There's more on how to use it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you very much!